# <Tensorflow object detection>TypeError: resize_images() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_aspect_ratio'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

```
cuda 9.0
cudnn 7.5
python 3.5.2
tensorflow-gpu 1.8
```

I don't know where the error occurred, I also tried python 3.6.3. This error will also occur. Please help.

I am training model_main.py file, but I get the following error.

```
python model_main.py --model_dir=F:/cindy/cindybackup/tensorflow1/test/training -pipeline_config_path=F:/cindy/cindybackup/tensorflow1/test/data/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --alsologtostderr --num_train_steps=1000 --num_eval_steps=10
```

It shows the following:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to
>   be 1.
>       WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0.
>   Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
>       WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplh3q4jn2
>       WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (.model_fn at 0x00000256FF7F1400>) includes
>   params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
>       WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "model_main.py", line 109, in 
>           tf.app.run()
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>           _sys.exit(main(argv))
>         File "model_main.py", line 105, in main
>           tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py",
>   line 439, in train_and_evaluate
>           executor.run()
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py",
>   line 518, in run
>           self.run_local()
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py",
>   line 650, in run_local
>           hooks=train_hooks)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 363, in train
>           loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 843, in _train_model
>           return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 853, in _train_model_default
>           input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 691, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
>           result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 798, in _call_input_fn
>           return input_fn(**kwargs)
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\inputs.py",
>   line 525, in _train_input_fn
>           batch_size=params['batch_size'] if params else train_config.batch_size)
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py",
>   line 149, in build
>           dataset = data_map_fn(process_fn, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py",
>   line 853, in map
>           return ParallelMapDataset(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py",
>   line 1870, in **init**
>           super(ParallelMapDataset, self).**init**(input_dataset, map_func)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py",
>   line 1839, in **init**
>           self._map_func.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function.py",
>   line 484, in add_to_graph
>           self._create_definition_if_needed()
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function.py",
>   line 319, in _create_definition_if_needed
>           self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\function.py",
>   line 336, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl
>           outputs = self._func(*inputs)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py",
>   line 1804, in tf_map_func
>           ret = map_func(nested_args)
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py",
>   line 130, in process_fn
>           processed_tensors = transform_input_data_fn(processed_tensors)
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\inputs.py",
>   line 515, in transform_and_pad_input_data_fn
>           tensor_dict=transform_data_fn(tensor_dict),
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\inputs.py",
>   line 129, in transform_input_data
>           tf.expand_dims(tf.to_float(image), axis=0))
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py",
>   line 543, in preprocess
>           parallel_iterations=self._parallel_iterations)
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py",
>   line 237, in static_or_dynamic_map_fn
>           outputs = [fn(arg) for arg in tf.unstack(elems)]
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py",
>   line 237, in 
>           outputs = [fn(arg) for arg in tf.unstack(elems)]
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py",
>   line 2264, in resize_to_range
>           lambda: _resize_portrait_image(image))
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
>   line 432, in new_func
>           return func(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 2063, in cond
>           orig_res_t, res_t = context_t.BuildCondBranch(true_fn)
>         File "C:\Users\wyh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1913, in BuildCondBranch
>           original_result = fn()
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py",
>   line 2263, in 
>           lambda: _resize_landscape_image(image),
>         File "F:\cindy\cindybackup\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py",
>   line 2245, in _resize_landscape_image
>           align_corners=align_corners, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
>       TypeError: resize_images() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_aspect_ratio'

Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not resolved yet in tensorflow models(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/)

I just removed the preserve_aspect_ratio in object_detection/core/preprocessor.py

```
align_corners=align_corners, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
align_corners=align_corners)
```